# characterData in mutation observer not working as expected

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

According to mutation observer [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/characterData), characterData property is used to specify whether or not to monitor the node or nodes being observed for changes to their textual contents.

I have changed characterData to false in Config but still I am getting the callback when text is changed

Code Below:

```
 var CONFIG = {
    childList: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true,
    attributeOldValue: false,
    characterDataOldValue: false
};
  var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {      
    for (var i in mutationsList) {
        try {
            if (mutationsList[i].type === 'childList' && mutationsList[i].addedNodes.length && document.getElementById('abc')) {
                document.getElementById('abc').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent = "changed text";
            }
        } catch (e) {
            
        }
    }
};
```

I am getting infinite callback in above code.

Comment: Of course. That's because the text was changed via node manipulation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It's working fine in chrome but not in other browsers. And as per the documentation it should not.

Comment: Contents can be changed by removing and then adding the entire text node. You can check the specification for textContent to see which behavior is correct.